# How much of a premium is paid to run computations on chain?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Compared against a traditional program how much more does it cost to run an equivalent EVM smart contract ?

I'm looking for some rough estimate like: the same program would cost 100x more in EVM smart contract than on a traditional server.

Answer (score 0):

well, when we talk about smart contract you only pay gas, so if you want to know how much it will cost to you, you need to know the gas price of your target chain and the gas of deploy the contract and call the functions you need to setup the contract, and only that, you don't have to pay any kind of bill for that, just the gas you spend